# Mimicking Pass-By-Reference in Python/Javascript Using Wrappers - Good Practice?

Tags: javascript, python, pass-by-value

Say I want to modify a number or some other primitive inside of a function. For example, something like this (note: pseudocode):

```
// apply fn to every value in a tree, in-order traversal
function treeReduce (tree, fn, result):
    if (tree == undefined) return
    treeReduce(tree.left, fn, result)
    result = fn(result, tree.value)
    treeReduce(tree.right, fn, result)

sum = 0
treeReduce(myTree, +, sum)
```

obviously this won't work, because `result` is just being reassigned, and the `sum` passed in won't see the modifications. So a common way I have gotten around this (in any pass-by-value language like Python or Javascript) is using wrappers:

```
// apply fn to every value in a tree, in-order traversal
function treeReduce (tree, fn, result):
    if (tree == undefined) return
    treeReduce(tree.left, fn, result)
    result[0] = fn(result[0], tree.value)
    treeReduce(tree.right, fn, result)

sumWrapper = [0]
treeReduce(myTree, +, sumWrapper)
```

However, I recently searched the internet to see if this is a common pattern, and can't find much information about it. Specifically, I'd like to know three things:

1. is this a common pattern?
2. is this good practice?
3. if not, any alternatives?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a bad practice, it resembles the monads of functional programming, as they are wrappers. I would pass a reducer function. Also consider creating an iterator, it can be useful for other things.

Comment: what do you mean by passing a reducer function? Isn't this already passing a reducer function `fn`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *could* be done like that, however it increases ["sideeffects"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) of your function which most coders would advise to minimise as much as possible. Instead you could use the function's *return* value for it. Your code would then still pass the "previous" (or "start") value as a primitive, but *return* the result.

Here is how it would look in JS (I took a less trivial `fn` to demonstrate it performs an in-order execution):

```js
// apply fn to every value in a tree, in-order traversal
function treeReduce (tree, fn, start) {
    if (tree === undefined) return start
    let result = treeReduce(tree.left, fn, start)
    result = fn(result, tree.value)
    result = treeReduce(tree.right, fn, result)
    return result
}

let myTree = { value: 1, left: { value: 2 }, right: { value: 3 } }

let result = treeReduce(myTree, (a,b) => a*a+b, 0)
console.log(result)
```

Note that the above can be written more concisely now:

```js
// apply fn to every value in a tree, in-order traversal
function treeReduce (tree, fn, start) {
    return !tree ? start
        : treeReduce(tree.right, fn, fn(treeReduce(tree.left, fn, start), tree.value))
}

let myTree = { value: 1, left: { value: 2 }, right: { value: 3 } }

let result = treeReduce(myTree, (a,b) => a*a+b, 0)
console.log(result)
```

In Python:

```py
import collections
Tree = collections.namedtuple('Tree', ['value', 'left', 'right'])

# apply fn to every value in a tree, in-order traversal
def treeReduce (tree, fn, start):
    return start if not tree else ( 
        treeReduce(tree.right, fn, fn(treeReduce(tree.left, fn, start), tree.value))
    )

myTree = Tree(1, Tree(2,None,None), Tree(3,None,None))

result = treeReduce(myTree, lambda a,b: a*a+b, 0)

print(result)
```

Both JS and Python also allow to extend this to the case where you would need to set multiple primitive values: functions can return arrays/lists/tuples/objects, which can then be assigned by unpacking/destructuring them into separate variables.

Comment: I am not sure if that would work, and it's a bit hard to explain why, so sorry if I get it wrong. You aren't passing the accumulator (in this case, `result`) to the right side of the tree. The reducer `fn` takes in the accumulator `result` and a node value, but you are calling it with `result` and the reduction of `tree.right`

Comment: though I can see now that it probably can be done with a return value instead of side effects, it will probably require a helper function, because you somehow have to pass the accumulator to the right side of the tree, so the helper function needs to take it in as an argument

Comment: True, I had taken the addition from your example, but to have in-order accumulation, you would have to pass the previous value as argument. I updated my answer.

Comment: ok so I was partially right, you had to pass the accumulator in as an argument, but you didn't need a helper function, which is nice. I feel like the "concise" version is kinda hard to read, but the first version has comparable readability as my original wrapper-based code, and has no side-effects, so I'm going to accept this answer. I have a feeling there are other examples that are not as easy to convert to return-style, but I will have to think about it more